# Android Studio 1.0.2 proguard rules

Tags: android, eclipse, android-studio, proguard

I imported an Eclipse project into Android Studio and now I'm trying to revive the proguard part. I have the following in build.gradle:

```
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
    }
}
```

and now the questions are:

1. where and how do I add the file proguard-android.txt and proguard-rules.txt?
2. The syntax/format of this file in ADT is the same as it was in Eclipse?

I now noticed that I also have cannot resolve symbol 'getDefaultProguardFile'

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide#TOC-Running-ProGuard) you can find some more information on what `getDefaultProguardFile()` does. In essence, Android provides two Proguard files for you to use, one with optimizations, one without.

As for your custom `proguard-rules.txt` file, put it (if it isn't already there) in the same place where your `build.gradle` file of your App is located. See the [SeriesGuide](https://github.com/UweTrottmann/SeriesGuide/tree/3c847294d2ea98b7e5451ecf16ee1d8090537a7c/SeriesGuide) repository for an example.

#### Edit

Your directory structure (as can be seen in the SeriesGuide repo linked above) should be something like this (directories like `src/` have been omitted):

```
.
├── app
│   ├── build.gradle # this is probably where you defined android { . . . }
│   │                # and thus `proguardFiles`
│   └── proguard-project.txt
└── build.gradle # setting up buildscript, maven repositories etc
```

Comment: Thanks, I will look into your reply, I just got to this post saying the cannot resolve... is a known issue that it yet to be resolved: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=69731

Comment: I copied the proguard-rules.txt from the eclipse project folder to the new ADT project folder and put the file in the same folder as the build.gradle but I'm not sure how can I add it to the project in ADT itself and under what folder should I do it.

Comment: Regarding the cannot be resolved.... that is not fixed yet, means the proguard cannot be activated? How can I know that proguard actually affected the APK I will generate?

Comment: I added the directory structure you should have, which is also the way you can see it in SeriesGuide as linked above, please check it out. As for the issue you linked, this should have no effect on the functionality of proguard.

Comment: I have the app folder and inside I have: manifests, java and res folders and on the same level as app, I have Gradle Scripts folder and inside it I have build.gradle (project) and build.gradle (module) and gradle.properties, settings.gradle and local.properties

Comment: What you are describing sounds like the *Android* perspective in Android Studio, not your file structure. Check either in the *Project* perspective or in your favorite file explorer.